# Xcode 6, iOS 8 could not load custom fonts

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts, xcode6.3

I'm struggling with custom fonts. I'm using Xcode 6.3 and iOS 8.3.
As in other application I do this steps:

1. Import `MerriweatherSans-Regular.ttf` (added to target) [image]
2. Added `MerriweatherSans-Regular.ttf` in `Info.plist` with key `Fonts provided by application`

But if try to print all fonts available Merriweather never comes out

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

The strange is with Xcode 6.1 all works fine.

Comment: Do you have that problem with TextField or TextView? I had some similar issue.

Comment: "added to target" Can you prove that?

Comment: Sure... see the image added in my edit

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong font name in your code. Click your font file and open the file inspector. It should have a "Full Name" property. Use that name as the font name in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why xcode 6.3 has this strange behavior but your font will appear in the list when you use it somewhere in XIB.